# jquery ui dynamic button with icon

Tags: jquery-ui, button, dynamic

I am unable to create the jquery ui button dynamically without text and with icon.

```
var $ctrl = $('<input/>')
    .attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn'})
    .val('Action')
    .button({icons: { primary: "ui-icon-close"},text: false});
```

This code creating ui button with text. how can i get the dynamic button with icon and without text.

Answer (score 0):

For an input of type "button", the "value" attribute is the text visible on the button. So the line

```
.val('Action')
```

is what makes text appear on the button.

If you remove this line, you will have a button with just an icon.

```
var $ctrl = $('<input/>')
    .attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn'})
    .button({icons: { primary: "ui-icon-close"},text: false});
```

Does the line mentionned above have a special purpose or is it just a copy / paste mistake ?

Comment: thanks for your reply its not working, it is displaying button without text only

Comment: After having removed .val('Action'), your code is an exact duplicate of the sample of JQuery UI button demo page, which is working... So i bet here on a very dumb mistake somewhere else. Can you reproduce it on a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above-mentioned options but they didn't work.

After doing lots of investigation I found the below solution and it worked

```
var $ctrl = $('').button({icons: { primary: "ui-icon-help"},text: false});
```